# Undefined index: email with fosuserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an existing app installed from git repo and know he should work, but having problems with launching it. App uses *fosuserbundle*
 and I'm getting following error on both login/sign up:

```
Undefined index: email in /var/www/relabld-old/website/vendor /doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php  on line 1704
```

although email field exists in my User class:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Relabld\CommonBundle\Entity\UserStatus;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Relabld\CommonBundle\Entity\ItemStatus;

use Relabld\CommonBundle\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Relabld\CommonBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="first_name_idx", columns={"firstName"}), @ORM\Index(name="last_name_idx", columns={"lastName"}) , @ORM\Index(name="full_name_idx", columns={"fullName"})} )
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, groups={"Registration","Basics"}, message="Email is already used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, groups={"Registration"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @CustomAssert\CustomUser
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     groups={"requestInvitation"}
     * )
    */
    protected $email;
    ...
```

What could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

Delete email field, this field already exists.